# Mysql adding new columns for the selection

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table

```
+-----+------------------+-------------+
| id  | name             |month_1      |
+-----+------------------+-------------+
|   1 | anna             |     15      |   
|   2 | bin              |     20      |
+-----+------------------+-------------+
```

When I make a selection I want to add one more column.

For example

```
SELECT id,name, money as month_1 FROM test where month(day)='1';
```

And I want to add a column, something like this:

```
SELECT id,name, money as month_1,money as month_2 
FROM test 
where where month(day)='1',where month(day)='2'

+-----+------------------+-------------+------------+
| id  | name             | month_1     |month_2  |
+-----+------------------+-------------+------------+
|   1 |anna              |     15      |       10    |
|   2 | bin              |     20      |       0     |
+-----+------------------+-------------+------------+
```

Comment: Please take a little time to format your question.  It's difficult to read.

Comment: You really need to take a SQL tutorial. This is so very basic.

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT id,name,
       SUM(CASE WHEN month(day) = 1 THEN money ELSE 0 END) as month_1,
       SUM(CASE WHEN month(day) = 2 THEN money ELSE 0 END) as month_2
FROM test 
GROUP BY id, name;
```

You may or may not want to include the month and year in the aggregation.

Comment: Shake that as!!